# Skype Video flicker and stays on top - ubuntu 15.10

Tags: video, skype

the video on skype is flickering (unless I turn of my video) and is always on top (even with my video off).
I am using the latest skype version and 15.10
anyone has any idea about it?
When I go to options of skype the video looks that it is working fine
Thank you

Comment: Lastest version for what the software center? Try Skype for Linux http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/

Comment: @DnrDevil I don't think it matters where you get Skype. It's so outdated for Linux platforms that the software center and direct downloads have the same versions.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. Skype use xvideo extension, and does not provide an option to switch to another. 
Try this config 
https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix

Comment: @DavidFoerster Danke!  **;-)**  Canned comment removed.

Answer (score 1):

there is a script that copies the needed 20-intel.conf file and the newest intel firmware:
http://www.linux-onlineshop.de/forum/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=317

It is in german, but you can see what it does there and make the same!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.